# $9a^2-a^4+2a^2b-b^2 $ how to factor this algebraic expression? Algebraic identities

Tags: factoring

I can't match any of the most common algebraic identities with this expression.

$9a^2-a^4+2a^2b-b^2 $

Once this algebraic expression is factored this should come out

$ (3a-a^2+b)(3a+a^2-b)$

Can someone tell me the name of the algebraic identity that you use to factor/rewrite this expression and how you have solved it?

Comment: Difference of two squares

Comment: First notice the binomial square, then recall the difference of squares identity. Or, if none of those clicks, consider it as a quadratic in $b$ and calculate the roots.

Comment: Straightforward:  $(3 a - a^2 + b) (3 a + a^2 - b)$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for the input, but I honestly I can't solve it. Do you mind writing it down? step by step. Is there any forum or website that would help me look at the right things in order to spot the algebraic identities?  I know that $a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ but I can't see it in here. The same goes for $ (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 $.

Comment: @BrandoJhaksaelArmas You miswrote the *difference* of squares identity. You'll use that identity with one of the squares being $9a^2 = \left(3a\right)^2$ and the other one as suggested in the posted answer.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for the heads up. I meant to write $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Separate the $9a^2$ out and focus on the remaining three terms:

$-(a^4-2a^2b+b^2)$

Allowing $u = a^2$ might make the algebraic identity (something to do with binomials) more visible. Move on from there.

Comment: My next move would be $ 9a^2 -(a^2-b)^2$

Comment: Yes, another identity(related to binomials pops up). See how there is $something^2$ - $something^2$?

Comment: Woooow this is so cool. I can see it now!! Thank you!!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: one more question. When can I put a negative sign in the middle of the expression ? only if there is already a negative sign in the expression? like in this case$-a^4.....$ $-(a^4.......)$

Comment: Yes, so:
The negative sign that we factored out is the same negative sign as before:
$-a^4+2a^2b-b^2 \to -(a^4-2ab^2+b^2)$
or more generally, you factor out a negative whenever you want, you just have to follow the rules of algebra
Eg:

$a^2+b^2 = -(-a^2-b^2)$, because a positive divided by a negative becomes negative. You can always factor it back in using the distributive law to see whether it matches your original equation

Comment: Thank you again!!